# ng-show not working properly - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS 1.6.6 to develop a web app. I'm using ng-show on my template to recycle it:

```
<div >
    <br/>
    <div class="form">
        <form data-ng-submit="objectHandlerVM.functions.objectHandlerSwitcher()">
            <button data-ng-show="objectHandlerVM.functions.where('/editObject/'+objectHandlerVM.object.idn)">Edit</button>
            <button data-ng-show="objectHandlerVM.functions.where('/createObject')">Create</button>
            <button data-ng-show="objectHandlerVM.functions.where('/deleteObject/'+objectHandlerVM.object.idn)">Delete</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is trying to show a different button depending on the url used to access.
Here is the code of the controller:

```
angular.module('objectApp')
.controller('objectHandlerCtrl', ['objectFactory','usersFactory','$routeParams','$location',
            function(objectFactory,usersFactory,$routeParams,$location){
    var objectHandlerViewModel = this;
    objectHandlerViewModel.object={};
    objectHandlerViewModel.functions = {
        where : function(route){
            return $location.path() == route;
        },
        readUserNameEmail : function() {
            usersFactory.getUser()
                .then(function(response){
                    objectHandlerViewModel.object.title= response.title;
                    objectHandlerViewModel.object.content= response.content;
                    console.log("Reading user with id: ",response.idn," Response: ", response);
                }, function(response){
                    console.log("Error reading user data");
                })
        },
        updateObject : function() {
            objectFactory.putObject(objectHandlerViewModel.object)
                .then(function(response){
                    console.log("Updating object with id:",objectHandlerViewModel.object.idn," Response:", response);
                }, function(response){
                    console.log("Error updating object");
                })
        },  
        createObject : function() {
            objectFactory.postObject(objectHandlerViewModel.object)
                .then(function(response){
                    console.log("Creating object. Response:", response);
                }, function(response){
                    console.log("Error creating the object");
                })
        },
        deleteObject : function(id) {
            objectFactory.deleteObject(id)
                .then(function(response){
                    console.log("Deleting object with id:",id," Response:", response);
                }, function(response){
                    console.log("Error deleting object");
                })
        },
        objectHandlerSwitcher : function(){
            if (objectHandlerViewModel.functions.where('/createObject')){
                console.log($location.path());
                objectHandlerViewModel.functions.createObject();
            }
            else if (objectHandlerViewModel.functions.where('/editObject/'+objectHandlerViewModel.object.idn)){
                console.log($location.path());
                objectHandlerViewModel.functions.updateObject();
            }
            else if (objectHandlerViewModel.functions.where('/deleteObject/'+objectHandlerViewModel.object.idn)){
                console.log($location.path());
                objectHandlerViewModel.functions.deleteObject(objectHandlerViewModel.object.idn);
            }
            else {
            console.log($location.path());
            }
            $location.path('/');
        }
    }
    console.log("Entering objectHandlerCtrl with $routeParams.ID=",$routeParams.ID);
    if ($routeParams.ID==undefined) objectHandlerViewModel.functions.readUserNameEmail();
    else objectHandlerViewModel.functions.readObject($routeParams.ID);
}]);
```

So, when I access that template to create an object, the url ends with "createObject" and it should show only one of the buttons, and the same with "editObject" and "deleteObject". But, don't know why, is showing the three of them.

I've also tried:

```
<button data-ng-show="objectHandlerVM.object.idn!=undefined">Edit</button>
<button data-ng-show="objectHandlerVM.object.idn==undefined">Create</button>
```

And it also shows both of them, which is confusing me the most...

Comment: ng-show works with boolean

Comment: @Sajeetharan Yes, I'm not pretty sure if it's the correct way to check the url. Is there any other way?

Comment: @JaimeAlcántaraArnela  what is tho console.log of `$location.path()` and `route`

Comment: Why are you using `data-ng-show`? Isn't it just `ng-show`? Are you using a custom directive?

Comment: @MohammadAliRony It's just to make it easier to me, should have added it here, excuse me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-show works with boolean, if you want to check the url, you can have a function to do that and return true/false based on that,

```
 <button data-ng-show="checkUrl()">Edit</button>
```

and in controller

```
$scope.checkUrl = function(){
    //add your logic
    return true/false;
}
```

Comment: Hmm sorry but, inside the controller, where should it be?

Comment: .controller('objectHandlerCtrl', ['objectFactory','usersFactory','$routeParams','$location',

Comment: you should use this.checkUrl since you are using controller as syntax

Comment: Ok but, if it works with boolean, should not the two lines below work?

Comment: you should do the same with other two lines as well

Comment: Ok, I'll give you the answer but, just to make it clear, could you post one of that lines fixed? Just to understand the solution.

Comment: well without having your variables its not possible to provide a working sample

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172434/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-jaime-alcantara-arnela).